# Java Performance and Security: Where to package static utility class?

Tags: java, static-methods

I have a program written in java that reads files from a location, analyzes them, and prints them in another location.  I have different classes to handle different file types; text, excel, delimited etc.

Some of the analyzing methods I run, like say, a method that truncates a line of text depending on a specific set of rules, are the same for all file types and independent of state, so I decided to make a utility class that has static methods that can be used by all the file reading/writing classes.

Question: Is there a security/performance/best practice difference whether I create a new package for the utility class, and therefor have to make all the static methods public, or I keep it in the same package where the methods can be protected?  Only the classes in the package containing the file handlers with need to use the util classes.

Comment: Creating a `com.test.util` package would be better to manage your code, however there's no security benefit to gain from it. No matter what you do with the packages, anyone can create a class in the same package or use reflection to use the protected methods. Only OSGI/Java 9 have meaningful package level security.